# CakePHP find() group and order by date complex conditions

Tags: cakephp, find, cakephp-2.7, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to get messages with their corresponding users, in order to display a chat list of profiles with their last message in chronological order.

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'Recepient' => array(
            'id' => ...
            'name' => ...
            ...
        ),
        'Message' => array(
            'content' => ...
            'created' => ...
            ...
        )
    ),
    1 => ...
)
```

and in order to retrieve the results, I've written this find() method:

```
$msgs = $this->Message->find('all', array(
    'group' => array('Recepient.id'),
    'order'=>'Message.created DESC',
    'conditions'=>
        array(
            'OR'=> array(
                array('recepient_id'=>$pid),
                array('sender_id' => $pid)
            )
    )
));
```

What I have:

- message with corresponding "Recepient",
- in chronological order

The problem:

- the query DOES NOT retrieve the most recent message from $recepient_id/$sender_id combination.

So instead of list of users with the last message, I have a list of users with a message. What's wrong with my query? Thanks for help!

## METHOD 2 results

I've created "chat_id" field in the database which is basically recepient_id+sender_id sorted alphabetically (because if user1 send user2 a message user1 is sender, later when user2 responds, he becomes the sender, so sorting will ensure two users will always have the same chat_id).

Than I added DISTINCT to the query:

`$this->Message->recursive = 0;
        $msgs = $this->Message->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('DISTINCT Message.chat_id','Message.*','Recepient.*'),
            'order'=>'Message.created DESC',
            'conditions'=>
                array(
                    'OR'=> array(
                        array('recepient_id'=>$pid),
                        array('sender_id' => $pid)
                    )
            )
        ));`

and it does NOT work! I am now getting multiple messages for the same conversation.

If I remove Message fields and Recipient fields from the query, I get correct amount of "chats".
`'fields' => array('DISTINCT Message.chat_id'),`
but that's not the solution.

CakePHP version 2.7.0
MySQL DB

## METHOD 3 results

`$msgs = $this->Message->find('all', array(
            'order'=>'Message.created DESC',
            'fields' => 'recepient_id, content, max(Message.created) as max_created',
            'group'=>'recepient_id',
            // 'contain' => array('Recepient'),
            'conditions'=>array( 'chat_id' => $chats )
        ));`

I gave up on single-find method to resolve this, so now 1.I am getting list of chats, 2.I want to find the last message from each chat.
Acording to http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ my find query should work. What happens is

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'Message' => array(
            'recepient_id' => '55e6d764-1444-4aad-a909-9042f07f76da',
            'content' => '1st msg',
            'created' => '2015-09-20 18:24:17',
            'created_nice' => '2  hours ago'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'max_created' => '2015-09-20 18:24:28'
        )
    ),
```

the field `max(`Message`.`created`)` is indeed showing the latest message from conversation but the 0=>Message array is for different message! As you can see `$results[0]['Message']['created']` time and `$results[0][0]['max_created']` are different!

Comment: Does `Message` have many `Recipient`? Have you checked the SQL query generated by Cake for this find? I suspect the query is not what you expect!

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Sounds like `distinct` is a term you should have a look at... There are exapmles with `distinct` in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)...

Comment: Do you know how to write a SQL statement for this? If so, share it. If not, at minimum you don't want to `GROUP BY` Recipient.id when your problem is _retrieve the most recent message from $recepient_id/$sender_id combination_. You need to state the database you are using also.

Comment: give us much context on what you mean by `list of users with the last message, I have a list of users with a message` . they don't sound different things to me

Comment: NO: Does Message have many Recipient? It belongsTo.
Cake version: 2.7.0

I've tried DISTINCT (CONCAT('recepient_id','sender_id')), eventually I ended up having the same results, DISTINCT did not reveal actually distinct results

I am using mysql, I've tried writing the sql query, gave up after some hours,

To the last comment: the difference is I need the last message, to create a list of conversations with the last message, like iMessage does as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! Working solution:

```
$db = $this->Message->getDataSource();
$chats = $db->fetchAll(
    'select id from (select * from messages order by created desc) Message
    where recepient_id = "'.$pid.'" or sender_id = "'.$pid.'"
    group by `chat_id`'
);
```

Above code will retrieve all messages, following the requirements. You can

a) **SINGLE QUERY** add mysql JOIN to include associated model (we keep the code single-query neat)

b) **TWO QUERIES BUT SMARTER** easier method, to select just "ids" of the messages and create another query that will have cake's build in containable behaviour. This might be better also because Behaviours will be applied.

You will have array tree as a result, to dig out the actual ids for next query use following:

`$chats = Set::extract("/Message/id",$chats);`

c) translate the solution to CakePHP query builder... :) up for a challenge?